# Enviar dados para o mesmo formulário é um bom método?

Tags: php, html

Eu tenho um formulário de login, que após dado `submit` ele é enviado para si mesmo com as informações via `POST`, e caso esteja errado, ele exibe uma mensagem de erro e mostra novamente o mesmo formulário. Fiz dessa forma para evitar criar páginas tipo: `login.php`, `validalogin.php`.

Fico me questionando se foi um bom método, pois reduzi o número de páginas, porém quando o usuário aperta <kbd>F5</kbd> a página reenvia novamente todos os dados. Se esse for um bom método, é possível corrigir o problema do <kbd>F5</kbd>?

Comment: Eu sempre utilizo dessa forma também, é mais fácil de controlar. Você pode passar pelo problema do F5 fazendo seus formulários com ajax. Além de evitar esse problema, você dá uma outra cara pro visual podendo trabalhar a resposta com callbacks de mensagens de erro/sucesso.

Comment: @Victor Mendonça Só uma dúvida o input submit continua sendo submit ou vira type button?

Comment: Você pode deixar como submit, mas aí você precisará dar um return false no onSubmit do formulário. É mais fácil colocar button =)

Comment: Por favor pessoas que lerem isso, usem `POST`. Já cadastrei em site, coloquei senha forte, deu um erro, não validou e a senha foi parar no histórico.

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues +1000! Dados confidenciais **nunca** devem ser transmitidos via `GET`.

Comment: Eu também trabalho dessa forma e concordo com o Victor que ajuda na organização. Dependendo da sua situação (script,  servidor e demanda da página) eu não me preocuparia com o problema do F5, já que o form nunca será validado. Uma vez o form seja validado/processado recomendo redirecionar (usando [header](http://uk1.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php) ) o usuário para uma página de confirmação (que pode ser a mesma) para evitar que o form seja enviado outra vez.

Comment: Uma dica básica pra formulários: associe uma função ao 'click' do botão 'Submit' do seu formulário para que ele seja desativado quando for clicado. Na resposta da requisição, se der erro ele libera o botão. Se ocorrer tudo bem, limpe o formulário e libere o botão.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uma outra forma de contornar isso e também garantir um pouco mais de segurança é utilizar um token de submit.

Exemplo: Quando alguém pedir a tela de login você cria um token, exemplo um uuid guarda e envia em hide no formulário. Assim que o formulário for enviado você verifica se ele existe na sua lista e marca como usado. Desta forma se o mesmo token for reenviado algumas vezes você não o reprocessará novamente.

Começa a melhorar a segurança também, lógico que vai muito mais além que o que exponho aqui, se alguém forjar o request da sua página com um scam, spam seja lá o que mais o atacante usar, você vai "garantir" que aquele formulário foi criado por seu sistema "e" que o token usado você o conhece, logo é uma boa situação. Assim se o atacante tentar enviá-lo novamente não terá sucesso pois o token já foi utilizado.

Mais sobre o ataque de [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A8-Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29)

É uma boa estudar os ataques top ten do OWASP, pois lá tem o problema e uma forma de solucionar os problemas.

Comment: +1 Boa dica... e quase não me sobram votos hoje.

Comment: O problema nesse caso é que se a pessoa voltar à página anterior para reusar o formulário para uma NOVA (e válida) entrada o UUID vai gerar um problema.

Answer (score 3):

Creio que isso pode ser contornado através de uma redireção. Faça um `POST` para seu formulário e, em caso de falha, faça um *redirect* (`302`) para si próprio - passando na *query string* os parâmetros de renderização (i.e. qual mensagem de erro que é para exibir). Assim o browser vai fazer um `GET` para o mesmo formulário, mostrar a mensagem como você quer, e se o usuário fizer <kbd>F5</kbd> o browser simplesmente vai repetir o `GET`.

O único inconveniente, creio, é que após o <kbd>F5</kbd> as mesmas mensagens de erro serão exibidas, a menos que você limpe a *query string* via JavaScript após a exibição do formulário.

Answer (score 2):

Creio que este é um bom método.

Do ponto de vista **funcional**, não há problemas em deixar a tecla <kbd>F5</kbd> reenviar os dados de login no caso da autenticação falhar. A operação é *idempotente*.

Entretanto, do ponto de vista de **usabilidade**, talvez seja melhor evitar isso e seguir a orientação do @mgibsonbr e fazer um redirect para si mesmo.

Além da *query string*, uma outra alternativa já usada em outras linguagens para que a mensagem de falha de login sobreviva a um, e somente um, `redirect` é usar o conceito de mensagens *flash*. Nunca usei em PHP, mas [este artigo](http://mikeeverhart.net/php/session-based-flash-messages/) possui uma descrição de como implementar isso.

Por outro lado, é possível também um **esquema de autenticação via Ajax** para evitar toda essa complexidade.

Quando o usuário clicar no botão de *submit* do formulário de login, faça uma chamada Ajax POST que retorne uma flag de *sucesso* ou *falha*. Se ocorrer falha, mostre em um campo na tela. Se ocorrer sucesso, faça via Javascript o redirecionamento para a página principal usando `window.location.href`. É uma solução bem simples, principalmente se você usa jQuery.

Como um bônus, você pode ainda implementar as duas soluções simultaneamente, sendo a versão Ajax adicionada na página de forma *não obstrutiva*. Se o javascript estiver desabilitado, o login funciona da forma "tradicional".